# http.send returns [object object] at the backend (Node + Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, object, xmlhttprequest

my http.send returns [object object] at the node.js backend.

```
    <script>
      const newExerciseForm = document.getElementById("newExercise");
      newExerciseForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const userId = document.getElementById("uid").value;
        const description = document.getElementById("desc").value;
        const duration = document.getElementById("dur").value;
        const date = document.getElementById("dat").value;
        const params = userId + "," + description + "," + duration + "," + date;
        http.open(
          "POST",
          "http://localhost:5000/exercisetracker-f0756/europe-west1/exerciseTracker/api/exercise/add",
          true
        );

        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
          //Call a function when the state changes.
          if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("exerciseTracker").innerHTML =
              http.responseText;
          }
        };
        http.send(params);
      });
    </script>
```

backend:

```
app.post('/api/exercise/add', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send('hitted');
})
```

can someone help me out how to fix this issue?
i have choosen the standard xmlhttprequest method due to the structure of the application.

Comment: You're sending a string of comma-separated values, which is supposed to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` , but it doesn't look like `params` is encoded that way (no '&', no "="). If you're sending a plain string, why not just use `text/plain`?

Comment: text/plain works instantly. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

terrymorse comment: use "text/plain" works instantly with the setup in the question.

```
 //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
```

Thank you!